# How do I programmatically track the app install source with the Facebook SDK for a given user ID?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm building an iOS and Android app and I integrated the Facebook SDK to track app installs caused by a Facebook Ad. I'm able to see aggregated data in [Facebook Analytics](https://www.facebook.com/analytics/) for my app, but I would like to be able to identify whether a given user in my database installed the app from a Facebook ad or not.

I set the UserID I have for my user in the App Events SDK using the [setUserID](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/current/facebook/com/facebook/appevents/appeventslogger.html/) method, but I was not able to filter the events reported by Facebook Analytics to get only data for the given user ID. Also, I would like a programmatic way to fetch this information so I can send it when the user registers (along the user profile).

Under the hood, the Facebook Analytics dashboard uses an undocumented GraphQL API endpoint `analytics_query`, would this endpoint support requests by User ID? Do I have to send this User ID as a custom parameter for an event?

In case this helps, my app also uses the Firebase SDK, but it seems the latter cannot identify people coming from Facebook Ads (which makes sense since it's made by Google).

Many thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @DanielZanchi We found a sort of workaround using [deep links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking). The general idea is that you put a `?app_install_source=<yourad>` in your Facebook ads. Then, with the you get the deep link in your app and let the backend know about it. Once you've done that, all you have to do is update your Analytics solution to store that.